# Eclipse: Keeping track of all the files that I have changed before checking in?

Tags: eclipse, version-control

When I have changed a lot of files I usually forget checking in some of them and this breaks the build. I have tried maintaining lists but it doesnt work. Is there any good plugin to Eclipse that tells me all the files that have been changed since my last checkin?

Comment: What version control system are you using?

Answer (score 10):

And in general you use the *Synchronize View*.  Team providers (Git, CVS) hook into it, and it will show you a delta between what's checked in and what is dirty in your workspace.

Use *Window>Show View>Other...* to open the view, or switch to the *Team Synchronizing* perspective.

EDIT: I'll just add if you are using EGit, there's also the *Git Staging* view.  It will show you all modified files for the current repo.

Answer (score 1):

The CVS tooling in Eclipse allows you to maintain changesets. This allows you to group together files - in synchronize view - which have changed for a particular task. More details can be found at http://www.peterfriese.de/using-cvs-change-sets/

Answer (score 0):

The [Egit](http://eclipse.org/egit/) which comes with Eclipse Indigo will mark any directory with modified content.

See the [Track Changes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Track_Changes) section of the Egit man page.
No need to install any extra VCS: all is included with the latest [Eclipse distro](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Comment: @Kaushalc: The Git repo could co-exist with your CVS repo, though, but this is definitively a different Version Control System. I mention it only because this is now the official one for all Eclipse projects and Eclipse itself: http://aniszczyk.org/2011/07/19/github-and-eclipse-git-repository-mirroring/